# Why is my sklearn t-sne function quitting before reaching its maximum iteration

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to run a tsne analysis on a square distance matrix. These are the commands I am using.

```
model = TSNE(n_components = 2,perplexity = 32, verbose = 10,n_iter = 1000, metric = "precomputed")
embeddings = model.fit_transform(D)
```

This is the output I receive: [output from tsne function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anfih.png)

It looks like the program is running through 75 iterations and then calling it good and quitting. When I plot the data from the tsne it's basically just a single dense blob. Why is the program quitting early and how can I make it run longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quitting because the **exit-condition** is reached.

Interpreting the log, the exit-condition is **probably a metric on the gradient**, called **gradient-norm** here. If needed, checkout the basics of [gradient-descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) to understand the intuition. As every iteration is making a step towards the negative of the gradient, tiny gradients will not do much to the objective (and will be interpreted as: we found a local/global minimum).

It looks like (still interpreting your log only):

```
if np.linalg.norm(gradient) < 1e-4:
    return solution
```

There is no merit to further do more iterations for this parameterization of the optimization-problem. The solution won't get better (in terms of minimization).

You can only try other parameters (resulting in other optimization-problems).

Comment: Thanks! So would this be a problem with the data I'm feeding in?

Comment: Might be the data, might be the parameters. I'm sure, you will find some parameters, where more iterations are needed, although this does not mean much in regards to your solution. It's a perceptual thing.

Comment: it's not necessarily a problem: what sklearn is saying is that it has found a local or global optimum, and it won't find a better solution by continuing to iterate.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution it found isn't very good - the data isn't clustered at all, it's just lumped together on one big bull's eye

Comment: Then try other parameters! But keep in mind, that this algorithm is trying so solve some hard problem (embedding many dimension on a 2d-plane is crazy enough...), is heuristic by nature and might need manual tuning.

Comment: Sounds good, I really appreciate the advice! (: I'll prepare myself for a thrilling day of tuning parameters